# How do i prevent a spring boot webapplication from accepting http requests while it is still starting up?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have a spring boot webapplication with a angular frontend. When i send a request using the angular app while the webapplication is still starting up it may occur that the webapplication can accept that request and will try processing it. I believe the application is capable of receiving requests the moment that the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` extending class has been initialized.

This causes problems when the rest of the classes have yet to fully initialize. For instance, when i try to log out a user that is still logged in while the webapplication is starting up, it may cause a SQLException because it can't find the database table `user` yet.

How do i prevent the application from accepting requests until the final class (the one annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`) has been initialized?

Comment: is your database table user created by your spring-boot application?

Comment: @cmlonder yes it is. The tables are created from the entities

Comment: Maybe this can be of help: https://reflectoring.io/spring-boot-execute-on-startup/. Most likely `@DependsOn` annotation and the `ApplicationReadyEvent` event seem like a viable solution.

Comment: But it already works similar to what you expect. Spring start searching its beans (Configuration etc.)  and injects Bean into the context starting from the class where you have SpringBootApplication (unless you give another context to search from, it is default behavior to start from the current package of your main class). Do you use any reactive libraries that may have asynchronous calls under the hood?

Comment: @cmlonder no i don't. The application is able to receive requests as soon as the API endpoints have been defined in `configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity)` of  `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the hint of @Fullslack.dev i've come up with the following solution.

```
@WebFilter(urlPatterns = {"/*"})
public class MyFilter implements Filter, ApplicationListener<ApplicationReadyEvent> {

    private boolean webApplicationReadyToAcceptRequests = false;

    @Override 
    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationReadyEvent applicationReadyEvent) {
        webApplicationReadyToAcceptRequests = true;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {

    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
            if(!webApplicationReadyToAcceptRequests) {
                httpServletResponse.setHeader("Retry-After","35");
                httpServletResponse.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE, "The server is currently starting up. Please try again in a moment.");
                return;
            }
            else
                filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
            }
    }

}
```

This is a filter class where every request must pass through first before it is presented to the @Controller and/or @Service annotated classes. If the variable `webApplicationReadyToAcceptRequests` is still false then the filter won't pass on the request downstream, instead it will send an error message response with httpstatus 503 (service unavailable).

Make sure you annotate atleast one of your @Configuration config classes with this:

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages={ "FolderWhereMyFilterIsLocated"})
```

This will make sure that spring is aware of the existence of the filter.

Comment: I feel, it is not a feasible solution for a business critical application, where several thousands of users accessing apps on same time.

Comment: @NewBee what alternative do you propose then.

Comment: This is a good solution for standalone applications and matches the same methodology that we are implementing for our applications. To @NewBee's point, Spring Boot provides a better solution when using a load balancer by checking the *readiness state* and only routing traffic to instances accepting traffic, but many environments do not have load balancers. More information: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-liveness-readiness-probes

Comment: It seems the boolean webApplicationReadyToAcceptRequests should be set as volatile.

Answer (score 0):

Approach with `ApplicationReadyEvent` is not good enough as it gets propagated **after** Spring web application has started up and web server is able to accept requests by that time:

`Tomcat started on port(s): 4134 (http) with context path ''`

and application is considered up and running:

http://localhost:4134/actuator/health
returns `{"status":"UP"}`

If you need to do some init before that then you have to attach that to spring context initialization, similarly to how it's done for DB connections. The simplest way is to have your "init" code in some spring bean's `@PostConstruct` method. Alternatively there is an old-school `InitializingBean` interface with a similar effect in `afterPropertiesSet()` method.

Comment: _Approach with ApplicationReadyEvent is not good enough as it gets propagated after Spring web application has started up and web server is able to accept requests by that time_. Thats the whole point @RomanSynakov. As soon as the `ApplicationReadyEvent` is triggered the `webApplicationReadyToAcceptRequests` boolean is set to `true` which then causes the application to accept all incoming requests.