# Spring Boot accepts network requests before ApplicationRunners are done

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

The spring boot documentation says the following:

"An application is considered ready as soon as application and command-line runners have been called, see Spring Boot application lifecycle and related Application Events." (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.spring-application.application-availability.readiness)

This does not mean that Spring Boot waits for `ApplicationRunner`s/ `CommandLineRunner`s to complete right?

Because in my case, one of my `ApplicationRunner`s is still running but the Spring Boot app already answers HTTP requests - which I dont' want.

Am I missing somehting here? Is there a better choice than using `ApplicationRunner`s?

I want code to be executed before the `ApplicationReadyEvent`, which I thought would only fire if all Application/CommandlineRunners are done (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.spring-application.application-events-and-listeners)

EDIT: My ApplicationRunner is defined as a component, it looks like this:

```
@Log4j2
@Component
@Order(value = 0)
public class ApplicationDependenciesReadinessChecker implements ApplicationRunner {


    @Autowired
    public ApplicationDependenciesReadinessChecker() {

    }

    /**
     * Checks whether all application dependencies of this application are alive and ready. As long as not all application dependencies are alive
     * and ready, this method won't terminate.
     *
     * @param args incoming application arguments
     *
     * @throws Exception if anything goes wrong
     */
    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {
        // my code 
    }
```

Comment: Indeed, Spring Boot does not wait for these runners to complete. I would like to give you an answer but I don't know myself how to achieve this. I've seen approaches with additional servlet filters that wait for a CountDownLatch on the active runner but it all sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: @NicoVanBelle I just found the solution but thank you very much for confirming my theory :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that using `ApplicationRunner` is not the correct way if you want to execute code BEFORE the `ApplicationReadyEvent` is fired (and thus don't want to handle network traffic before that code ran). The Spring Boot documentation is very misleading regarding this concern unfortunately.

Instead, one should use the `SmartInitializingSingleton` interface. The code that is defined in a component that implements `SmartInitializingSingleton` (inside the `afterSingletonsInstantiated()` method) definetly runs before the `ApplicationReadyEvent` and Spring waits until the code there has finished.

Answer (score 1):

Exact, "being run" doesn't mean "being run to the end" in that case.

What works as intended and synchronously:

- Initializing Beans
- `@PostConstruct` s
- ...

See also:

- [How do i prevent a spring boot webapplication from accepting http requests while it is still starting up?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63779539/592355)
- [Start Spring Boot refusing traffic at first](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76018718/592355)

A working sample, which rejects traffic as long the "init" is running:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Demo.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    InitializingBean init() {
        return () -> {
            System.err.println("initializing..."); 
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(60); // long running task...
            System.err.println("...done!");
        };
    }

    @RestController
    static class DemoController {
        @GetMapping
        public String welcome() {
            return "HELLO!";
        }
    }
}
```

When we need application arguments:

```
@Autowired
ApplicationArguments args
```

...works also with "initializing bean".

Comment: I will have a look at `HealthIndicator`, thank you very much :)

Comment: welcome&appreciate! (researching this,) I combined application runner and health indicator interface ... it is "nice"/it works, but they cannot prevent "web serving"...while with an "offline server" (approach) a (fancy) health indicator seems useless.

Comment: Good to know. I will stick with my `SmartInitializingSingleton` solution, because it prevents Spring from serving requests.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**

The `ApplicationContext` is already totally configured by the time runners are called, so the TomcatWebServer is already running and accepting network requests.

---

I assume you're bootstrapping the application using

```
SpringApplication#run(Class<?> primarySource, String... args)
```

By looking at it's source code, it's visible that the runners are the last thing to be executed during the initialization, meaning that, if you're using Embedded Tomcat as the webserver, the `AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext` is created and, when its `refresh()` method is called, the `TomcatWebServer` is initialized and is able to accept network requests.

The code below from `SpringApplication` class dictates the behavior you're experiencing and, in fact, it is the expected behavior.

```
DefaultBootstrapContext bootstrapContext = createBootstrapContext();
ConfigurableApplicationContext context = null;
configureHeadlessProperty();
SpringApplicationRunListeners listeners = getRunListeners(args);
listeners.starting(bootstrapContext, this.mainApplicationClass);
try {
    ApplicationArguments applicationArguments = new DefaultApplicationArguments(args);
    ConfigurableEnvironment environment = prepareEnvironment(listeners, bootstrapContext, applicationArguments);
    Banner printedBanner = printBanner(environment);
    context = createApplicationContext();
    context.setApplicationStartup(this.applicationStartup);
    prepareContext(bootstrapContext, context, environment, listeners, applicationArguments, printedBanner);
    refreshContext(context);
    afterRefresh(context, applicationArguments);
    Duration timeTakenToStartup = Duration.ofNanos(System.nanoTime() - startTime);
    if (this.logStartupInfo) {
        new StartupInfoLogger(this.mainApplicationClass).logStarted(getApplicationLog(), timeTakenToStartup);
    }
    listeners.started(context, timeTakenToStartup);
    callRunners(context, applicationArguments);
}
```

The invocation of the method `callRunners(context, applicationArgument)` is the last invocation of this method. The line `refreshContext(context)` delegates the context refreshing to the context itself (`context.refresh()`).

The `AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext` extends `ServletWebServerApplicationContext`, which initializes the `TomcatWebServer` on refreshing, so Tomcat is already started and the DispatcherServlet is already registered within the webserver before the execution of runners.

Also, before runners run, all the mappings defined through annotations like `@GetMapping`, `@RequestMapping`, etc are also registered.

This means that Tomcat is fully enabled before runners are executed and therefore it is able to receive requests.

The quote

> An application is considered ready as soon as application and
> command-line runners have been called, see Spring Boot application
> lifecycle and related Application Events.

is probably referring to the fact that if an exception is thrown by any runner, the app will probably be shutdown, so it is safer to say that the application will be 100% ready after all of these runners have finished.

Comment: "so it is safer to say that the application will be 100% ready" --> then the Spring team should add a `Application100PercentReadyEvent` to make this more clear :D :D Joking aside, thanks for looking into the code and also confirming my theory. I think the Spring team could definetly enhance the documentation situation, so that other people don't fall into the same trap.

Comment: @Walnussbär Fair enough, I got your point. I guess you can suggest these enhancements on the documentation on their Github

Comment: Sounds reasonable, I will do that!